# How to use a EGORefreshTableHeaderView.

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am using EGORefreshTableHeaderView in my app.

In that I am refreshing one part of the app and showing the last updated date using egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceLastUpdated method. Also in another part of the app, I am refreshing some content. Also I am showing the last updated date and time, but I am unable to differentiate the last updated date and time between the two update.
How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to implement EGORefreshTable separately in every view you want to update your content. You can not use same for all other part of the app. Still you can differentiate with some kind of app. It is hard to answer without knowing about your app structure and what do you meant by another part of app.

Comment: @deeps: another part of the app i mean another view. two views are getting updated. but the last updated date time is same for both the views but these two get updated in diffrent time.any helps?

Comment: Did you take common EGORefreshTable for both views ? or both have different EGORefreshTable ?

Comment: @deeps : both use same EGORefreshTable

Comment: Hmmm then that's your problem. You can either take both different or can put flag to differentiate both views. For example ifFirstView==TRUE then show this date else show other date etc. Let me know.

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to help you without knowing your code structure. Just for a **Hint** you can take one bool variable in appDelegate file and set that to yes or not depending upon what viewcontroller you are in. And store both updated date somewhere so you can set it accordingly flag. Let me know.

Comment: @Deeps let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1005/discussion-between-barbgal-and-deeps)

Comment: I think you want to get the same 'last update datetime'? yes?if so, use

- (NSDate*)egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceLastUpdated:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{
 
 return [NSDate date]; // you can save the date variable to somewhere, then both views will get the date. 
 
}